# how to deselected UITabbar in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

hi when i start my application UITabbar is show but no one tab is selected by default and i want to set my application detail view to set for launching time without selected any tab.i m using my custom tabbar for application so how can i make this ? do you have any idea please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is a `selectedItem` property in tabBar. Also there is `-(void)select:(id)item` method. I believe that if you'll cal that method passing `nil` it will deselect all the items. Haven't tried it by myself thought...
Hope that it helps.

Comment: its not working in my case .have you any other idea ragarding same ?

Comment: Hmm...
I can think of setting `selectedItem` property to nil by yourself along with calling `-(void)setNeedsDisplay;` on you tabBar instance to make it redraw itself with new state. (There may be possibility that it will actually redraw itself when you'll put nil to that property, but I don't know it for sure)

Comment: ok thanx . do you have any idea about how to get class name of current screen ?

Comment: Do you mean current `UIView` or the controller of that view? And I believe you mean top-most when you say current. Am I right?